# Issue when launching CVAT development environment

Tags: cvat

I am trying to add sound related features to CVAT but I need to launch the CVAT development environment in order to test them.
However, when following the instructions on the [documentation](https://opencv.github.io/cvat/docs/contributing/development-environment/), I have a problem.
I got to the *Run CVAT* section without any problem but when I run the *server: chrome* configuration, I get the following error in the chrome browser
[image: chrome_error].

And this is the error in VSCode

[image: error_1]

[image: error_2]

[image: error_3]

I searched on the CVAT documentation and in the source code but I did not find anything that could help me. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of error messages.

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't post my question with the error in text format because it was treated as spam. I prefered to post it as an image rather than not post it at all. Should I remove the images ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are encountering is most probably associated with insufficient storage space on your device. You must have a minimum of 10% free space available on your storage device in order to run CVAT tool successfully. Run docker-compose down then free up space on your disk drive at least 10%, then do docker-compose up again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the cvat_opa container as it says in CVAT docs [here](https://opencv.github.io/cvat/docs/contributing/development-environment/):

Just run the following command after you launch `server:debug` VSCode job:

```
 docker run -d --rm --name cvat_opa_debug -p 8181:8181 openpolicyagent/opa:0.45.0-rootless \
 run --server --set=decision_logs.console=true --set=services.cvat.url=http://host.docker.internal:7000 \
 --set=bundles.cvat.service=cvat --set=bundles.cvat.resource=/api/auth/rules
```